# `write()` and `read()` not working properly

Tags: c, pipe

What I basically have to do: I have an array with 10 random integers and I need to have two child; one will compute the product of the even index and the other will handle the odds. Once that is done the parent process will multiply those two values together and print it out.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
  int ans[2];
  int array[10];                                //main array
  int i;
  srand (time(NULL));                           //for not the same numbers

  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
  {                                             //array filling
    array[i]= ( rand() % 10 + 1);               //from 1 to 10 random numbers
    printf("Array: %d \n",array[i]);
  }
  int children = 2;                             //number of child processes
  int *product=0;                                // var to store the product sums

  int fd[2];
  pipe(fd);

  int arraymax[2];                              //the two products

  for(i=0;i<children;i++)
  {                                             //for 10 children
                                                //child processes
    if(fork() == 0)
    {
      printf("checkpoint 1\n");
        close(fd[0]);                                //close reading

        for(int j=i;j<sizeof(array)-1;j+=2)
        {
            product+= (array[j]*array[j+2]);
        }
        write(fd[1], &product, sizeof(*product));     //write the max number into the pipe
        printf("the product is: %d\n", *product);
        close(fd[1]);                                //close write
        wait(NULL);
        exit(0);
    }                                               //parent process
    else
    {
      printf("checkpoint 2\n");
        wait(NULL);
        close(fd[1]);                                //close write
        /* read pipe */
        for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
        {
          read(fd[0], &ans , sizeof(*product));
        }
        close(fd[0]);                                //close read
    }
  }
  printf("Total answer is: %d \n", (ans[0]*ans[1]));
  return 0;
}
```

and here is what the output is:

```
Array: 10 
Array: 7 
Array: 9 
Array: 5 
Array: 4 
Array: 4 
Array: 8 
Array: 5 
Array: 7 
Array: 1 
checkpoint 2
checkpoint 1
checkpoint 2
checkpoint 1
Total answer is: -432399864
```

The answer should not be anywhere near that number it's giving me. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: If the parent closes the write side of the pipe during the first iteration of the loop, then the second child will not be able to write to it.  Check the return value of `write` (well, really your debugging will be much easier if you put error checking on everything!).  Also, there's no need to call `wait` in the children.

Comment: Note that `for(int j=i;j<sizeof(array)-1;j+=2)` is counting the number of bytes, not the number of integers, in the array. This will not lead to happiness (undefined behaviour).

Comment: @WilliamPursell If I don't close for writing the program gets stuck after the first child writes to the pipe.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes thank you for pointing that out. Been a while since I've coded in C

Comment: Did you mean `&ans[j]` here `read(fd[0], &ans , sizeof(*product));`? Otherwise, `ans[1]` never changes, and since it's not initialized you could very well end up with the number you're seeing.

Comment: Note that `product+= (array[j]*array[j+2]);` is a funny way of producing the product.  It also accesses out of bounds of the array.  You probably need to set `product` to `1` before the loop, then use `product *= array[j];` in the loop.  Your children are inheriting the array, which simplifies your life.  You will probably be OK with two children writing on the same pipe for the size of `write()` that you're doing (each write is small enough to be atomic). However, there's no guarantee which product will be returned first. It doesn't matter here where the result is commutative, but in general…

Comment: `product` is also a pointer, which doesn't make much sense to me. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @Acuriousone Yes, you need to close the pipe, but you are doing it too soon.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you. (This does not address the odd and even part. Hope you can figure it out)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
  int ans;
  int total = 1;
  int array[10];                                //main array
  int i;
  srand (time(NULL));                           //for not the same numbers

  for(i=0;i<10;i++)
  {                                             //array filling
    array[i]= ( rand() % 10 + 1);               //from 1 to 10 random numbers
    printf("Array: %d \n",array[i]);
  }

  int children = 2;                             //number of child processes
  int product=0;                                // var to store the product sums

  int fd[2];
  pipe(fd);

  int arraymax[2];                              //the two products


  for(i=0;i<children;i++)
  {                                             //for 10 children
                                                //child processes
    if(fork() == 0)
    {
      printf("checkpoint 1\n");
        close(fd[0]);                                //close reading

        for(int j=i;j<sizeof(array)/sizeof(int)-2;j+=2)
        {
            product+= (array[j]*array[j+2]);
        }

    printf("the product: %d\n", product);
        write(fd[1], &product, sizeof(product));     //write the max number into the pipe
        //printf("the product is: %d\n", product);
        close(fd[1]);                                //close write
        wait(NULL);
        exit(0);
    }                                               //parent process
    else
    {
      printf("checkpoint 2\n");
        wait(NULL);
        close(fd[1]);                                //close write
        /* read pipe */
        for(int j=0; j<2; j++)
        {
          read(fd[0], &ans , sizeof(product));
        }
    total *= ans;
        close(fd[0]);                                //close read
    }
  }
  printf("Total answer is: %d \n", (total));
  return 0;
}
```

You had some errors with pointers I've corrected them. And to get the product of results from two children i've used a separate variable(total).

And the loop here goes out of bound

```
for(int j=i;j<sizeof(array)-1;j+=2)
    {
        product+= (array[j]*array[j+2]);
    }
```

it should be like

```
for(int j=i;j<sizeof(array)/sizeof(int)-2;j+=2)
    {
        product+= (array[j]*array[j+2]);
    }
```

if you have any questions feel free to ask.

Comment: Thanks I'd already figured out some of those mistakes, the problem I'm having right now is that the second child never actually writes the product to the pipe and I think it's because I close it at the parent process. But if I don't close it my program just freezes at that point

Comment: yes it seems so, if you found the solution please post, i'd give it a try too.

Comment: I'm still trying to work that out. Will update post when I figure it out.